# Can I add an action to the Navigation Bar's title view?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, action, uinavigationbar, title

I have a vision for something that I want to achieve, but I don't know if it is possible. Basically, I want my navigation bar's title (the one that is colored and formatted all pretty) to act as a button. I want to be able to press the nav bar title text, and be able to respond to that as a normal action.

Is this possible? I have tried a number of things, and have gotten the blank area to respond to touch as a button, but I can't get the button and the pretty text to be there together.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a view with transparent button, and set it as the titleView for your navigationBar.

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but it took away the title text when I did that...as if I could have one or the other, not both.

Comment: You're right, titleView is a custom view, you need set title by `customTitleView.title`(here you can set it as UILable) instead of `self.title`. You can add tapGesture for it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an UIButton with a transparent image and put it over the navigation controller